# What is the correct approach to allow inline styles in the Content Security Policy (CSP) of a Single Page Application (SPA)?

Tags: javascript, security, nginx, webpack, content-security-policy

The application I am working on uses a component library which relies on a CSS-in-JS implementation. This means, I need to allow inline style tags as part of the CSP. Up until now, I have used the `style-src 'unsafe-inline'` directive. However, this is less secure and is being flagged by our security audit because of the possible risk of Cross Site Styling attacks.

My understanding is that for an application using Server-side Rendering (SSR), you can generate a `nonce` on the server on page load and inject that into the client application, so that `<style>` tags have the same `nonce` as the CSP. This would prevent a user from being able to add a style without knowing the `nonce`, which changes each time the page loads.

However, for a Single Page Application (SPA), there is no way to inject a server-generated `nonce` into the client application before execution. It's possible to inject it at build-time, either by hard-coding the value or making it generate each time you run a build (e.g. with Webpack). However, that is not much more secure than keeping "unsafe-inline" because an attacker can find and use the `nonce` up until the point the next build is deployed.

One solution might be to use CSP hashes instead, where the `style-src` hash is generated based on the content hash of the styles. It looks like you can do this with a plugin like [CSP HTML Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/slackhq/csp-html-webpack-plugin), which generates the CSP and adds the corresponding hashes to `<style>` tags. However, this means the CSP I have needs to be moved from an NGINX response header to a `meta` tag in the HTML. There are certain directives that are not supported this way, such as `frame-ancestors`. I could use `X-Frame-Options` response header to get around that though.

Is the hash technique mentioned above the correct approach to take or am I missing other possible solutions that may be better or simpler to implement? I may be wrong about some assumptions as well, so just looking for a bit of clarity here.

Comment: You can specify multiple policies in response header and meta tag, i.e. you can keep your current CSP set by nginx in the header and add another one in meta tag just to address the inline styles.